# Llenar tabla HTML con petición AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html

tengo el siguiente código pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Mi código `HTML`.

```html
   <?php 
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['rango']!='Administrador'){
       header("Location:index.php");
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="">  
 <input type="submit" id="RevisarUsuarios" value="Verificar">
  
   <table border="1" id="miTabla">
      <caption>Verificar</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th colspan="3">Registros Base de Datos</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Usuarios</td> 
       <td>Correo Electronico</td> 
       <td>Rango</td> 
    </tr>

  </thead>
   <tbody id="contenido">
    
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </form>
 
 <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> <!--Utilizar libreria JQUERY-->
 <script src="js/codigoadmin.js"></script> <!--TODO lo que utilize JQUERY deberá ser referenciado           despues de la libreria.-->
</body>
</html>
```

Al momento de hacer click en mi botón con id `#RevisarUsuarios` realizo la petición al servidor al siguiente archivo `PHP`.

```
<?php

    require_once('../Modelo/class.conexion.php');
    require_once('../Modelo/class.consultas.php');

    $consultas = new Consultas();
    $datos = $consultas->cargarUsuarios();

    $results = (count($datos) > 0) ? $datos : array("error"=>"No hay opciones en la BD");
    $arrayJson = json_encode($results);
    print_r($arrayJson);

?>
```

Este me regresa un `json_encode` que posteriormente intento procesar en mi archivo `JS`. Que es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#RevisarUsuarios').click(function(event) {
        alert('Realizaré la petición');
        $.get('Controlador/cargarUsuarios.php', function(data) { 
            alert('Obtuve los datos');
            console.log(data);
                        $.each(data, function(idx, opt) {
                          alert('Estoy recorriendo el registro numero: ' + idx);
                  $('#mitabla contenido').append('<tr><td>' + opt.nickname + '</td><td>' + opt.email + '</td><td>' + opt.nickname + '</td></tr>');

                console.log(opt.nickname + ' ' + opt.email + ' ' + opt.rango);
        });
    }, 'json');
    });
});
```

Los 3 `alerts` se muestran correctamente. Con el ultimo `console.log` visualizo los datos que trae la variable data por la petición `AJAX`, como se muestra en la imagen, mas sin embargo no logro anexarlos a mi tabla ya intente hacerlo directamente a la tabla y al tbody de esta, pero no lo consigo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por cualquier aportación.

Comment: Prueba cambiando **$('#mitabla contenido')** por **$('#mitabla #contenido')**

Comment: Te falta un # en contenido:  $('#mitabla #contenido').append ...

Comment: Ya se lo agregué sigue sin funcionar. El `console log`, y los `alerts` siguen mostrándose correctamente

Comment: ¿Así `$('#mitabla').append('<tr><td>' + opt.nickname + '</td><td>' + opt.email + '</td><td>' + opt.nickname + '</td></tr>');` no funciona?

Comment: No, ya intente hacerlo con el id de la `tabla` y con el id del `tbody`, mas sin embargo en ninguno de los 2 funciona correctamente.

Comment: Ohhh el `tbody`, es por eso. Prueba así: `$('#mitabla tbody').append('<tr><td>' + opt.nickname + '</td><td>' + opt.email + '</td><td>' + opt.nickname + '</td></tr>');`

Comment: Tampoco, solo se siguen desplegando los alerts y el console log correctamente, ya los puse como comentarios para ver si ellos interferían en algo, mas sin embargo, sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Que raro, ¿lo pusiste como te dije: `$('#mitabla tbody').append(...)` o sea poniendo `tbody` no el id del tbody.?

Comment: Si, ya lo solucioné cheque un codigo similar donde por `AJAX` llenaba un `SELECT` o `COMBOBOX` y la unica diferencia era esta línea

Comment: ¿Qué línea? Poniendo el id de la tabla y la palabra `tbody` a continuación debería funcionar.

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` despues del evento click y ya. Se desplegaron los registros en mi tabla teniendo `$('#mitabla').append.....
`

Comment: Todavía más raro. ¿Si le quitas el preventDefault deja de funcionar? Debe haber entonces alguna otra llamada que no estamos viendo de tu código.

Comment: Así es, si se lo quito deja de funcionar, los id's de los elementos del DOM son únicos, no los repito en ningún otro lado, los archivos php y el js son exclusivos para este uso que planteo aquí. Gracias por tu apoyo.

Comment: Si cambias el input por un `<button id="RevisarUsuarios">Verificar</button>` creo no tendrías el problema del preventDefault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complementando tu respuesta, @antonio291093...

El error decaía por que el elemento al que estás haciendo clic es un input de tipo `submit`, y su comportamiento natural es enviar la información. Sin embargo, para hacerla llegar a su destino, debe de recargar el navegador a la página hacia donde tu estás haciendo la petición con el método `.$get`.

En otras palabras, la acción por defecto de un `submit`, siempre recargará el navegador y hará que pierdas el DOM actual.

Para prevenir esto, `.preventDefault()` de jQuery, cancela el comportamiento y/o defecto natural de un elemento. Te pongo otro ejemplo:

El comportamiento natural de un `elemento <a>`, es siempre dirigirte hacia una página web. Con `.preventDefault()`, previene ese comportamiento y no le permite al elemento realizar esa acción.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#conPD').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Evite su comportamiento por defecto con PreventDefault');
  });
  
  $('#sinPD').click(function(){
    alert('Este es el comportamiento por defecto del elemento');
  });
});
```

```css
a{
 display:block;
 margin:25px;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank" id="conPD">Soy un link CON .PreventDefault()</a>
<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank" id="sinPD">Soy un link SIN .PreventDefault()</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<p data-height="300" data-theme-id="25171" data-slug-hash="PJNMPP" data-default-tab="js,result" data-user="Hoose" data-embed-version="2" data-pen-title="Evitar comportamiento por defecto de los elementos con preventDefault()" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/Hoose/pen/PJNMPP/">Evitar comportamiento por defecto de los elementos con preventDefault()</a> by Hoose (<a href="https://codepen.io/Hoose">@Hoose</a>) on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
<script async src="https://production-assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

**EDITO:** Parece que StackOverFlow en Español no permite las redirecciones hacia otras páginas. Checa mi CodePen https://codepen.io/Hoose/pen/PJNMPP

Comment: Gracias, me ayudaste a comprender la situación el ejemplo fue muy claro, pongo tu respuesta como solución al problema, por la aclaración muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Insertando la linea:

> event.preventDefault();

Después del evento click en el botón se solucionó el problema, y ya se despliegan correctamente los registros en la tabla. Espero le sea de utilidad a alguien mas.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#RevisarUsuarios').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Realizaré la petición');
        $.get('Controlador/cargarUsuarios.php', function(data) { 
            alert('Obtuve los datos');
        $.each(data, function(idx, opt) {
            //alert('Estoy recorriendo el registro numero: ' + idx);
            $('#mitabla').append('<tr><td>' + opt.nickname + '</td><td>' + opt.email + '</td><td>' + opt.nickname + '</td></tr>');
            console.log(opt.nickname + ' ' + opt.email + ' ' + opt.rango);
        });
    }, 'json');
    });
});
```