# ¿Cómo puedo insertar código html y javascript desde el codbehind (C#) al frontend ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

mi duda está en que debo crear una tabla dinamica la cuál genero desde el codbehind una vez presionado el botón de consulta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta tabla contiene unos campos fijos que es la que se encuentra con bordes rojos y la parte azúl es lo que se genera dinamicamente, en este caso sólo sale el mes de abril pero al lado deberá aparecer después el mes de mayo y así sucesivamente, es un ejercicio de mi parcial y ya el código javascript lo tengo, se encuentra en una variable tipo string en el codbehind, el punto está en que no sé cómo insertar ese código en el frontend de asp.net, si alguién pudiera ayudarme, se lo agradecería.

Comment: Buen día. Te sugiero desde tu codbehind envíes al frontend los datos que generaran las demás columnas que serán dinámicas; y desde luego, los datos a mostrar (las filas de datos) con ello "no importara" las columnas y los datos pues siempre tendrás conocimiento de cuantas generar y leyendas que tendrán así como los datos.

Comment: Es que el tema está en que no sé qué componente usar para mandar los datos, no sé si hay algo como lo hay con Chart JS que existe la etiqueta <Canva/> en el aspx y desde el codbehind con el ScriptManager puedo referenciar al Id de esa etiqueta y pintar mi grafica enviando el script en una variable tipo string, esa es mi duda

Comment: No pones código para sugerirte (cambios) realizar; sea Ajax o formes todo el html desde el servidor; si creas (en formato JSON) que tenga todo, desde las columnas con sus datos que son fijos; asimismo los dinámicos. Tengas jQuery o JavaScript con "como llenar tabla html javascript" y otras búsquedas  encontraras ejemplos como poblar la tabla (si es HTML) o DataTable; según tu caso/escenario. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/160026/rellenar-una-tabla-html-desde-javascript-dinamicamente  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103500/llenar-tabla-html-con-petici%C3%B3n-ajax